# Unable to start the Administrative console of IBM WebSphere Application Server.Cause:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am trying to start the Administrator Console of IBM Websphere but it is giving me error while starting the server,i am using following command to start the server

```
C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSr2\bin>startServer.bat server1
ADMU0116I: Tool information is being logged in file
           C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSr2\logs\server1\startServer.log
ADMU0128I: Starting tool with the AppSr2 profile
ADMU3100I: Reading configuration for server: server1
ADMU3200I: Server launched. Waiting for initialization status.
ADMU3011E: Server launched but failed initialization. startServer.log,
           SystemOut.log(or job log in zOS) and other log files under
           C:\IBM\WebSphere\AppServer\profiles\AppSr2\logs\server1 should
           contain failure information. When i looked into log files error is java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. How do i come out of this situation?
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try increasing the initial size of JVM heap. This can be done in `server.xml` located at `WAS_HOME\profiles\PROFILE_NAME\config\cells\CELL_NAME\nodes\NODE_NAME\servers\SERVER`. You should modify element `<jvmEntries>` and adjust or add attribute `initialHeapSize`:

```
<jvmEntries initialHeapSize="1024">
```

The suitable value will depend on your environment.

Comment: i think it is already set there have a look at property that you have mentioned..... <jvmEntries xmi:id="JavaVirtualMachine_1183122130078" verboseModeClass="false" verboseModeGarbageCollection="false" verboseModeJNI="false" initialHeapSize="1024" maximumHeapSize="1024" runHProf="false" debugMode="false" ..............>

Comment: When OutOfMemoryError occurs, WAS usually generates a heap dump. It can be found in profile directory in file named like heapdump.<date>.<timestamp><pid>.phd. What amount of memory does it show?

Comment: how to open .phd file? On notepad++ it is showing some binary contents.

Comment: Sorry, you should check corresponding javacore.<date>.<timestamp><pid>.txt file. There is a section "MEMINFO subcomponent dump routine" in it.

Comment: this is what there    ------------------------------------------------------------------------
0SECTION       MEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1STHEAPFREE    Bytes of Heap Space Free: 504FE8 
1STHEAPALLOC   Bytes of Heap Space Allocated: 10000000 
NULL

Comment: wheni introspect those files i found that  : 
0SECTION       MEMINFO subcomponent dump routine
NULL           =================================
1STHEAPFREE    Bytes of Heap Space Free: 24E6A8 
1STHEAPALLOC   Bytes of Heap Space Allocated: 10000000  i.e. memory is available still it is giving that error what is the resolution for this?

Comment: It looks like the heap is occupied by something. Do you have any applications installed on that server that might eat memory on startup? You have always the option to analyze heap dump using IBM Heap Analyzer - https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/groups/service/html/communityview?communityUuid=4544bafe-c7a2-455f-9d43-eb866ea60091